# Dynamic RouteConfig in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I know I can change the routing in the RouteConfig in my MVC application:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "epage", url: "view/SpecificURL", defaults: new {
    controller = "ePage",
    action = "Index"
})
```

but I am wondering how to redirect for values comming from a db.  There is one row in my db that has titles .  So for each title comming from the db I want to  redirect to a specific url
ex.

the title in db may be `"pink"`  I want `www.mydomain.com/pink`  to be rerouted to a specific url .  The URL that I want it redirected to is also in the db.  I looked at lots of questions on this and can not seem to find any that dynamically change the routing of urls

Comment: Why do you need to redirect it to a specific URL?  Couldn't you do a lookup for "pink" in your database and have it simply return the appropriate content?

Comment: I know this isn't the same question but it seems like you are looking for the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971468/depth-first-nested-routing-in-an-asp-net-website/13980352 What you want to do is create your own route handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Then in your controller (the HomeController in my case):

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    ContentResult cr = new ContentResult();
    // Do a DB lookup here to get the data you need from the database to generate the appropriate content.
    cr.Content = id;
    return cr;
}
```

This example simply returns the string that was sent.  So now if I browse to `http://localhost/mysite/pink` I would get "pink" back as my result.  You could easily use this method to then do a lookup to your custom database to determine the correct content to return.

If your existing routes don't let you take this route :), then you can always do a SQL query in the `RegisterRoutes` method and populate the route table from that.

Comment: The problem with  url: "{id}", is that will ignore all my other controllers

Comment: Some of it depends on how you have your routes setup.  I have the route listed plus             
`routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Base",
    url: "{controller}/{action}");`  and it returns the string if I only put in a single param, but if I put in a controller & action, I get that route.